# X Button (close) position in mobile app

Tags: mobile-application, position, close

I'm Designing a mobile app (for android and iOS)

the "side menu" icon is on the left and when needed changes to "back".

when using the X button - should i position it the same as "back" - on the left or to put it on the right side for the screen.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or a wireframe sketch?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtw1niu4r9g3rts/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-16%20at%2015.40.15.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pvs03p5bm66gic/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-16%20at%2015.39.46.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest the "X" to be placed on the right side. as the action perform the least priority to close or leave the page and hope in your application it represent to close the page.

Better to align it on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Right Top corner.

Reasons:

1. 70 - 90 % of world population is right handed. So easy for right thumb to press it.
2. In OS point of view more than 70% of world population are used to Windows OS on which it's to the top right corner and people usually search there.
3. You can place it on Right bottom corner(like few android browsers introduce URL bar at the bottom of screen) but that's not appropriate as accidentally user may press it.

Comment: Why do you think that the fact there are lots of Windows OS users out there means that users of Android and iOS will expect a button on the top right? A desktop OS used with a mouse is very different to a hand held device that doesn't use a Windows metaphor.

Comment: People have used Windows OS since a long time before android. So their mind is set to that position irrespective of the OS or device they use. So psychologically UX always go with the majority people.

Comment: Also the left end is always for the title of the page unless and until the page is in Arabic